# Connect to wireless network via another computer's ethernet port

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, debian, ethernet

I have a computer running Debian 7.0 that is connected to a wireless network

I have a second computer that only has Ethernet, and there is nowhere to plug it into a router directly.

Is there any way I can get to the wireless network/internet through the first computer that is on the wireless network (and has an available Ethernet port).

I have read about `brctl` and it looks like you're unable to use it with `wlan0`.  I'm looking for some direction on how to go about solving this.

If necessary, I can connect through one of two other computers that have Windows 7 and Windows 8 (respectively) and free Ethernet ports as well.

Comment: You can use brctl to bridge a wireless port and a LAN port - in fact that is how dd-wrt and openwrt create an AP client where the ethernet and WIFI are on the same lan.

Comment: Can you advise what you mean by "there is nowhere to plug it into a router directly" ?   If there is a limit to the ports on the PC this does not make sense.  If not, the best solution may be to buy a cheap switch and use that.   It is possible to set a Linux box up to bridge or route (and I've done both, multiple times), but if you need to ask the question, its almost certainly not worth the effort and problems introduced into the network for a single PC.

Comment: @davidgo I mean the router that is actually connected to the internet directly.  I could get the two pc's plugged into another router/switch.